# Two repositories act differently with favicon

Tags: angular, .net-core, favicon

I moved my repository to different origin and then pulled it in new catalog on my machine.
This is .NET Core API with Angular client. What happened is fact that new instance of repo after build doesn't show favicon which is used also as logo.
I get 404 on request. What is interesting the old instance is at the moment exactly the same revision and works perfectly fine (shows favicon).
I tried to replace new catalog contents with old but it didn't change anything (Git client also shown no changes). I use Google Chrome with disabled cache (other browsers act the same). App config is OK and works on old instance.
Does anybody have idea what may be going on? I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found something here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071
My project was stored in path that contained '(' and ')' which caused problems.